# Bootstrap 4 toggle how to toggle just one element at click not all

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, toggle

I fighting with an annoying problem: I have 3 elements side by side on the bottom of the page (fixed). I added bootstrap4 toggles to show up only text when user click an image and it works... but toggle all images up not only one. I suppose it's not a huge problem but after many attempts, I failed. Maybe somebody knows the solution.  this is page: www.ourway.pl .

```css
 .carousel {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 100vw;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 10px;
    }
 .card-text {
        margin: 5px 5% ;
        text-align: justify;
        text-justify: auto;
        line-height: 25px;
    }
  .card-img-top {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: block;
        border-radius: 80px;
        border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) ;
        text-align: center;
        align-content: center;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.4/css/tether.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


   

 <section class="container-fluid p-0 topcard">
       <div class="row justify-content-center" >
       <!-- Carousel -->
          <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="8000">
             <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
               <article class="col">
                <div class="card carousel-style">
                 <div class="card-block p-0">
                  <h2 class="card-title">Rumunia - Sinaia</h3>
                    <img class="card-img-top opacity" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" src="/static/rumunia/woloszczyzna/sinaia/cover.jpg" alt="Card image cap" title="Kliknij aby rozwinąć opis">
 

             <p class="card-text collapse" id="demo" >Dziś zapraszamy Was do      historycznej krainy zwanej Wołoszczyzną, gdzie u stóp gór Bucegów leży urokliwe miasteczko Sinaia, które upodobała sobie para królewska budujac tu swoją zapierającą dech letnią rezydencję Peleş.</p>
            <a class="btn" href="/Rumunia/woloszczyzna/sinaia/opowiesc.html" title="Relacja">Opowieść</a>
            <a class="btn" href="/Rumunia/rumunia-wskazowki.html#Sinaia" title="Wskazówki">Wskazówki</a>
            <a class="btn" href="/Rumunia/woloszczyzna/sinaia/galeria.html" title="Galeria">Galeria</a>
             </div>
            </div>
           </article>

           <article class="col">
            <div class="card carousel-style">
             <div class="card-block p-0">
              <h2 class="card-title">Polska - Promnice i okolice</h3>
               <img class="card-img-top opacity" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" src="/static/polska/slask/promnice/cover.jpg" alt="Card image cap" title="Kliknij aby rozwinąć opis">
              <p class="card-text collapse" id="demo2">Dziś zapraszamy Was na Śląsk, a dokładnie w okolice Promnic, gdzie czeka na Was mnóstwo atrakcji, takich jak pałace, zamki, urokliwa ścieżka wokół jeziora, zagroda żubrów, skansen czy możliwość zwiedzania Tyskiego Browaru. </p>
              <a class="btn" href="/Polska/slask/promnice/opowiesc.html" title="Relacja">Opowieść</a>
             <a class="btn" href="/Polska/polska-wskazowki.html#Slask" title="Wskazówki">Wskazówki</a>
             <a class="btn" href="/Polska/slask/promnice/galeria.html" title="Galeria">Galeria</a>
                 </div>
                </div>
               </article>

               <article class="col">
                <div class="card carousel-style">
                 <div class="card-block p-0">
                  <h2 class="card-title">Polska - Schronisko na Kudłaczach</h3>
                   <img class="card-img-top opacity" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"src="/static/polska/beskidmakowski/pcim-kudlacze/cover.jpg" alt="Card image cap" title="Kliknij aby rozwinąć opis">
                  <p class="card-text collapse" id="demo3">Jeśli szukacie pomysłu na krótką popołudniową wycieczkę w okolicy Krakowa to polecamy pętle z Pcimia przez schronisko na Kudłaczach!</p>
                  <a class="btn" href="/Polska/BeskidMakowski/Pcim-Kudlacze/opowiesc.html" title="Relacja">Opowieść</a>
                  <a class="btn" href="/Polska/polska-wskazowki.html#BeskidMakowski" title="Wskazówki">Wskazówki</a>
   <a class="btn" href="/Polska/BeskidMakowski/Pcim-Kudlacze/galeria.html" title="Galeria">Galeria</a>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                 </article>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>  
         </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for including the site! it made it easy for me to try some things out.

I would add the following CSS rules:

```
header{
    z-index:1;
}

article.col{
    height:100vh;
}

.card.carousel-style{
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

If you want more of an explanation, then let's look at the relevant structure:

```
<div class="carousel-item">
    <article class="col">
        <div class="card carousel-style"></div>
    </div>
    <article class="col">
        <div class="card carousel-style"></div>
    </div>
    <article class="col">
        <div class="card carousel-style"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On your site, the `.carousel-item` div has its height expand to fit the tallest of its children (one of the `.card`s). So when you click on a `.card` and it expands, the `.carousel-item` gets taller. All of the `.card`s are positioned by default to be at the top of their parent, so when the parent gets taller they all go up.

If you add the CSS rules that I listed above, then the `.carousel-item` becomes as tall as the page, but each `.card` stays as low as it can, due to `position:absolute` and `bottom:0px`.  Unfortunately, `position:absolute` messed with some of the horizontal centering, so I had to add `width: calc(100% - 30px)` in order to keep each `.card` centered in its `article.col`.

EDIT:

Another effect of the `.carousel-item` becoming as tall as the page is that it covers up your navbar. So we need to make your header stand out on top of the `.carousel-item` so that users can still click on it. So set the `z-index` of the `.header` to be anything greater than 0 and it should work.

Comment: Wonderful! it's working!  My first question. I'm impressed. Thx a lot!!

Comment: p.s. after implementation of your solution my navbar stopped working...

Comment: Sorry about the broken navbar. I just edited my answer to include a fix for the navbar that I was able to verify on your site. If you appreciate the answer, please do upvote or accept the answer :)